# ckeditor page hang with multiple textarea

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have more than 50 textarea on page,
If i apply ckeditor to all of them, it hangs on the page for 10-15 second for its code loading.

is there any solution for this, to load smoothly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, use fewer textareas, or find a way to lazy-load them

Comment: Load `CkEditor` on focusing text-area